# python (Chave liga/desliga)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá.

Eu estou aprendendo a programar em python3, já faz algum tempinho. Sou usuário Ubuntu.

Venho criando um script já faz algum tempo, agora quero melhorar ele, já procurei alguns módulos e alguns exemplos mas não encontrei nada.
Preciso de um modelo de script que faça o seguinte: Quando eu aperte Ctrl+Shift+I ele execute uma função com um laço. E quando eu aperte outra sequencia Ctrl+Shift+P o laço pausa, mas quando pressiono Ctrl+Shift+I ele retorna a fazer a função ou a recomece. E por fim quando eu apertar Ctrl+Shift+D ele encerra o programa em geral. Preciso que ele faça isso sem que eu esteja com o teclado no terminal, pois o script estará analisando imagens. Por favor me ajudem mandando um exemplo de script, ou algo que possa me ajudar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Oi Leonardo. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Primeiramente, este site não é um fórum. Faça o [tour] e leia [ask], ok? A sua dúvida tá um pouquinho ampla, por que você não a divide em partes (vc pode abrir várias perguntas se precisar)? Por exemplo, parece que a parte central da sua dificuldade e saber se é possível capturar uma combinação de teclas, executada no sistema operacional (já que não vai ter terminal aberto) via Python. Seria isso? Se sim, sugiro editar esta pergunta e focar nessa dúvida.

Comment: Ah, eu adianto que é pouco provável que dê pra fazer isso só com Python. Talvez vc precise usar algum recurso do seu Ubuntu pra executar scripts em Python, e nesses scripts usar algum recurso compartilhado (um arquivo em disco, uma memória compartilhada, etc) para manter o estado da sua "chave" como ligada/desligada. Um exemplo sobre a execução de shell script (que dá pra transpor para executar Python): https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540961

Comment: Oi Luiz - acho que eu cobri o que precisa "alem do Python" e como ligar isso  com Python na minha resposta.  Mas se a opção fosse usar um programa esterno a partir do shell scirpt que "espere ctrl + shift + i ", a mesma chamada a um programa externo pode ser feita a partir do Python. 
A pergutna para qual voce aponta, no entanto, fala sobre a execuçãod e qualquer programa - nao importa se é em Python ou nao. É só a configuração de um atalho do sistema para iniciar um programa - e não tem nada a ver com shell.

Comment: @jsbueno Sim, é verdade. Eu só estava tentando ajudar o AP, mas não pesquisei a fundo como vc. Bela resposta, aliás. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Desdobrando sua pergunta

Python é uma linguagem de uso genérico - serve para qualquer coisa. Só que para fazer qualquer coisa, ela tem que poder se conectar a entradas e saídas com os dados que ela quer processar.

Um programa em Python acessa mais facilmente os argumentos que foram passados na linha de comando, a entrada e saída do terminal - divididas em linhas de texto, e qualquer arquivo disponível nos ambientes que está rodando.

Para poder processar eventos tais como "ctrl + shift + I" pressionado no ambiente de janelas (e não no terminal onde o programa está em execução), cliques do mouse, movimentos em frente da câmera do computador, etc... - ele tem que interfacear com o Sistema Operacional, de alguma forma, para que o evento possa chegar até o seu programa.

Isso é feito através de bibliotecas e módulos externos (você também pode fazer diretamente, se souber quais chamadas fazer ao sistema operacional - sem usar um pacote terceiro - mas isso pode ficar MUITO difícil, MUITO rápido).

Então, você tem que entender que opções do seus sistema operacional e componentes dele são capazes de capturar eventos como os que você quer, e como passar esses eventos para o seu código Python.

## Quais bibliotecas pesquisar

E por outro lado, uma pergunta como essa deixa de ser uma pergunta "simples" de Python, para ser uma pergunta que requer alguém que tenha conhecimento bem especializado de um desses componentes.

Adiantando então - como você está no Linux, teria que interface com uma camada de compatibilidade do X11 - mas outros componentes do seu sistema já abstraem um pouco disso pra você. Em geral, os componentes capazes de "observar" eventos globais na interface gráfica vão ser as bibliotecas com toolkits de Widgets - o Python pode interfacear com Qt, GTK+ e Tkinter, dentre outras.

Dessas, o Ubuntu pré-instala as interfaces para GTK (mas a essa altura nem sei se o que ele instala de novo é usando o Gtk k clássico ou gtk3 + gobject introspection)  - e tem uma biblioteca que é distribuida por padrão com a linguagem Python, mas a instalação padrão do Ubuntu não inclui - que é o tkinter.

O tkinter seria mais simples, e mais universal - então, primeira coisa - buscar entender se o Tkinter pode capturar um evento global de teclado -  mas parece que não, ele só pode realmente receber eventos que aconteçam na janela do programa.

Repetindo a mesma busca com Python GTK3, aparece um exemplo no StackOverflow em Inglês que é quase exatamente o que você precisa:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613435/how-to-make-global-keyboard-shortcuts-with-python-and-gtk3

Então verifique se você tem instalado aí o pacote "python3-gobject"  ou similar (esse é o nome do pacote no Fedora).

## O que precisa ser diferente no seu programa

Note que o uso de bibliotecas que interagem com a tela e com o mouse, em geral, requerem um paradigma diferente de programação - em programas no terminal em que interagimos com "print" e "input" - o programa sempre está executando alguma coisa, ou está esperando o usuário. Quando a interação é com eventos da janela gráfica, o "esperando alguma coisa" se torna esperar eventos do sistema de fora do seu programa. Então em geral o programa é feito de outra forma:

Uma parte do programa faz o "setup", declarando as classes, janelas e controles que serão usados - e o mais importante - declarando **quais partes** do programa vão responder a eventos do sistema. Podem ser eventos de "fechar a janela principal", "click no botão Ok", "usuário pressiona `<Ctrl><alt>I` em qualquer ponto da tela" - esse setup sempre indica funções ou métodos que serão chamados quando o evento acontecer (eles levam o nome de callback).

A segunda etapa da execução chama o "loop principal" da biblioteca gráfica escolhida. Isso efetivamente pausa o seu programa, e retorna o controle para o sistema operacional. Então nenhum código seu roda, até que chegue u evento pré-cadastrado, e uma das suas funções de callback é executada.

Então é difícil adaptar um programa que interage com "print" e "input" para usar eventos do ambiente gráfico - mesmo que seja SÓ um atalho de teclado - o correto é re-escreve-lo de forma que ele funcione nesse novo paradigma, orientado a aguardar eventos.

## E um exemplo para encerrar:

Então o seu script pode ficar na forma:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Keybinder', '3.0')


from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Keybinder
from gi.repository import GObject


KEY_START = "<Ctrl><ALt>I"
KEY_STOP = "<Ctrl><Alt>P"
KEY_TERMINATE = "<Ctrl><Alt>D"

def init(*args, **kwargs):
    Keybinder.init()
    m = Main(*args, **kwargs)
    print("Iniciando aplicação - pressione {} para agir, {} para sair".format(KEY_START, KEY_TERMINATE))
    Gtk.main()

class Main:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Salva os parametros para seu método principal

        # Bind callback keys:
        Keybinder.bind(KEY_START, self.start, None)
        Keybinder.bind(KEY_STOP, self.stop, None)
        Keybinder.bind(KEY_TERMINATE, Gtk.main_quit)
        # A partir dos parametros passados, configure
        # todos as variáveis que sua função principal
        # vai precisar como atributos do objeto
        # self.inicio = 0; self.dir="/tmp/", etc...
        # Deixe todo o código até o ponto em que você teria um
        # "while True" ou equivalente no seu codigo original

        # Este binding faz o runtime do gtk chamar sua funcao principal
        # quando o programa estiver rodando
        self.running = False

    def start(self, *args):
        self.running = True
        self.execute_once()

    def stop(self, *args):
        self.running = False

    def execute_once(self, *args):
        if not self.running:
            return

        # Aqui ponha o corpo de um loop da sua função
        # como se fosse o conteúdo do "while True"
        # guarde todas as variáveis que precisam ser
        # preservadas em atributos da instância
        print("Executando uma vez")
        ...

        # e agende a próxima execução desse loop principal
        # isso é necessário para que o sistema continue responsivo.
        # o tempo minimo de agendamento é 1ms -
        # se precisar repetir o corpo da função antes disso,
        #use um "for" ou "while" interno.
        GObject.timeout_add(200, self.execute_once)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```

PS - note que esse script faz exatamente o que você pediu - exceto que eu uso "ctrl + alt" em vez de "ctrl + shift": esta combinação não funcionou pra mim - procure documentação do Keybinder,- pode ser que não seja escrito "I" - ou talvez, mu sistema de janelas consuma esse tipo de atalho, antes de passa-lo para o programa.